# Where does standard output go in ubuntu / gnome auto started scripts?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

i have a script being started with gnome. that script is set to autostart with gnome automatically via system > preferences > startup applications. so where does the standard output of such an auto started program go?

To add some background information: I want to debug by analyzing the program's messages printed to its standard output. Just looking for the place where it goes. I remember, that the output is shown in the console when restarting gdm, but something like `cat /dev/vcs7` does not help.

Comment: to add some background information: i want to debug by analyzing the program's messages printed to its standard output. just looking for the place where it goes. i remember, that the output is shown in the console when restarting gdm. but something like `cat /dev/vcs7` does not help.

Comment: Possible same on askubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/289537/how-can-i-view-stdout-stderr-of-a-startup-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

stdout and stderr are eventually redirected in the X startup to `~/.xsession-errors`, so all its children have that redirection as well.

Comment: technically it's done in the session startup scripts, or by GDM if that is used.

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect normal and error output at the beginning of your script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec > /tmp/$0.$$.log 2>&1

...

echo "This text would go into the .log file"
```

Then when the script gets executed you'll be able to peek into the corresponding log file and see what's going on.

I hope this helps you!